# Upload fail with JSON

Tags: json, wcf, post, ios6, xcode4.5

I am trying to send image files from an iPad to WCF-based service.  I'm using JSON, Base64 for the image data.  The wcf service works fine - I've tested it independently (with the JSON string my app generates) using a tool from Mike Gledhill's superb tutorials.  From my iPad app I can send/receive small JSON strings no problem, but not bigger ones with images (~1MB).  The wcf service throws an 'endpoint not found' error.  Why does this work from my json tester but not the iOS app?

iOS code:

```
+(int)writeJSONDataToURL:(NSString *)urlString dictData:(NSDictionary *)dictData
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//    NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonString length]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Reply from web layer: %@", theReply);
    return 0;
}
```

And the wcf service:

```
       [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "addImage")]
    int AddImage(Stream JSONdataStream);

       public int AddImage(Stream JSONdataStream)
    {
        int result;
        try
        {
            // Read in our Stream into a string...
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JSONdataStream);
            string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // ..then convert the string into a single "Image" record.
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Image i = jss.Deserialize<Image>(JSONdata);
            if (i == null)
            {
                // Error: Couldn't deserialize our JSON string into an "Image" object.
                result = 0;
                return result;
            }

            byte[] imgBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(i.LocalPath);
            ELDataContext dc = new ELDataContext();
            Image newImage = new Image()
            {
                // imageid is autoincrement
                QuoteID = i.QuoteID,
                ImageDate = i.ImageDate,
                ImageNotes = i.ImageNotes,
                Thumbnail = imgBytes
                // ignore localpath
                // ignore localimageid
            };

            dc.Images.InsertOnSubmit(newImage);
            dc.SubmitChanges();

            result = 1;
            return result;
        }
```

Web.Config for the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ELConnectionString" connectionString="***"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ELWS.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ELWS.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="../Service1.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicBinding"
            contract="ELWS.IService1"
            behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
      </service>
    </services>   
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>        
        <binding name="basicBinding" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                  />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>   
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ELWS.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Whats the value of url. Did you check if url is correct. Also are you able to call even a single method from iOs

Comment: Figured it out yesterday. ID10t error... case different on one letter for the specific method I was trying to hit, which is why every other method worked fine.  Not sure why it worked from the tester, maybe case not an issue there.  So you're on the money, and thanks for responding!